# Parse a PIPE delimited field into seperate fields (MS ACCESS 2007-2013)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a database in MC Access 2017-2013 where the fields are stored as a PIPE delimited string. Now I want a way to parse these fields in a SELECT query in separate fields.

Here an example of my database and the PIPE delimited field:
[image: Database Example]

The field contains 9 Pipes. So I want to separate the field in 10 fields.

Here an example of the Output:
[image: Output Example]

I would be great, if someone could help me.
Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 3):

You need a VBA function in a standard module to implement the splitting, e.g.

```vb
Public Function SplitPipes(str As String, i As Long) As String

    Dim arSplit As Variant

    arSplit = Split(str, "|")
    ' Check that arSplit has enough elements
    If i - 1 <= UBound(arSplit) Then
        ' Split creates a 0-based array, but it is easier to start with index 1 in the query
        SplitPipes = arSplit(i - 1)
    Else
        ' out of elements -> return empty string
        SplitPipes = ""
    End If

End Function
```

Then you can use this function for every single field like this:

```sql
SELECT SplitPipes([Strategic Group],1) AS Destination, 
       SplitPipes([Strategic Group],2) AS SE,
       ...
FROM yourTable;
```

<s>Note that the function currently has no error handling whatsoever.</s> Added :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I added the VBA Function as modul and I can see it under the access objetives as modul. But in the query i get the error: "Function unknown". What do I have to follow when I add the modul?

Comment: @Peter: the function can't "be" a module, it must be inside a module. Like in this example: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/vbabasics2010/basics01.php . Open the Immediate Window with Ctrl+G, type `? SplitPipes("abc|def", 1) <return>`. Does that work?

Comment: Hi, i added it in a module. Here a Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhj82rwki39a2hn/Unbenannt6.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @Peter: Ah, I see. Giving the module the same name as the function can confuse Access. Rename the module to e.g. `mSplit`. --- After that, calling the function from a query should work. If not, please edit your question and add the full SQL of the SELECT query.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks a lot. One more question. Sometimes the Pipe delimited field has less values and less Pipes. Then the VBA function does not work. It is possible to add a error handling for this?

Comment: @Peter: yes: by checking `UBound(arSplit)`, see edit.